# PCIE to USB/Thunderbolt for Graphics Card

Tags: usb, graphics-card, pci-express, thunderbolt

I have a MacBook Pro Retina 13" with 8GB RAM and i5 processor and wanted to get better graphics performance out of it. I saw a couple of companies that have already made eGPU housings (such as Akitio), but those were well over my budget. Is there a way to utilize the USB or thunderbolt ports of the MacBook Pro and make my own external eGPU setup?

Comment: if there was a cheaper way, why would these external eGPU docks exist?

Comment: USB would be too slow, Thunderbolt might be possible, been a while since I looked at such devices though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thunderbolt is a complex standard; and I'm not sure if it's even open. I think you'd need to buy an expensive Intel controller chip ([DSL6340](http://ark.intel.com/products/87401/Intel-DSL6340-Thunderbolt-3-Controller), iirc?); and even then, it's no simple electrical-engineering task.

Look at it this way: transferring data in the *tens of gigabits* per second is an impressive electrical-engineering task. Much more so when you have an active component negotiating and mediating that alternate-mode communication. I'd guess that this isn't a very approachable project on your home bench. :P